# A particular case in factorizing the different ideal (Marcus Number theory, Ex. 28 chapter 4)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm having trouble with the exercise above. I know that everything I need comes from this specific part, that I have no idea at all how to solve:

> Assume $L/K$ to be a normal extension and call $R,S$ the rings of integers of $K,L$ respectively. Assume $Q \trianglelefteq S$ to lie over $P \trianglelefteq R$. Call $e:=e(Q/P)$. Prove that $Q^e \mid diff(S|R)$ if and only if $Q$ lies over a prime $p$ dividing $e$.

Could you please help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately this sort of local question is a weak point of Marcus. If you know how to work with localizations, that will make this much easier. See Prop 13, chapter III of Serre (Local Fields) for a proof along those lines.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to use localizations. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes, you can try to take the localization proof and “fix” it by using something in $Q-Q^2$ instead of a uniformizer but often you then need to work harder to pick the right element in there. Maybe that’s a place to start.

Comment: I will try that, thank you!